# How to convert an IN clause having actual values into a join clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to convert an IN clause which consists of actual values and not a subquery using join clause.

```
select max(c1) from t1 where t1.id IN (
1,2,3,4......1000
)
and t1.c2 = something
```

How do I convert this query into an join clause?

Comment: create recursive cte t2 returning the values 1 to 1000. join.

Comment: Are you asking explicitly about how to join on the sequence of integers from 1 to 1000, or on any arbitrary list of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a data-set by using an inline `VALUES`, and use aliasing to give that data-set and name and column names.

```
SELECT
    yourData.id, map.b
FROM
    yourData
INNER JOIN
(
  VALUES
    (1,2),
    (2,4),
    (3,8)
)
  map(a,b)
    ON map.a = yourData.a
```

Comment: I tried this but in the array values, I am using uuid's. It throws this error when I execute this, `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text = uuid `

Comment: @krishnasai - Then you need to cast your string representation to an actual UUID datatype.  `'A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'::UUID`

Answer (score 2):

Use `generate_series` if your sequence is increasing linearly

```
select max(c1) from t1    
join generate_series(1, 1000) ids on t1.id = ids
where t1.c2 = something
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but I am not. The select sequence is actually a list of uuid's.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
 with cte as
    (
    select 1 as col union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all
    ---------
    -------
    select 1000
    ) select max(t1.c1) from 
       cte join t1 on cte.col=t1.id where t1.c2=something
```